# Disable Qt warnings in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2008

We use VS 2008 Professional and the Qt Visual Studio Add-In to develop a Qt 4.8.4 application. I would like to set the warning level to 4 (all warnings), but for our own code only. If I set a warning level >= 2 under project properties, I get several hundred warnings from Qt header files we `#include`.

Unfortunately, it seems VS does not have an equivalent of gcc's -isystem option. I have tried enclosing Qt `#include`s between `#pragma warning(push, 0)` and `#pragma warning(pop)` with limited success. Auto-generated moc_*.cpp files still cause warnings about code in Qt header files. It is also quite cumbersome.

Do you know of any other way to achieve this? I'm finding it hard to believe all Qt/MSVC users have their warnings muted or skim through hundreds of irrelevant warnings after building.

Comment: I am currently compiling most of my code (uses Qt + other libs) with warning level 1. However I would like to increase that because it has bit me more than a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one way to do this: touch almost every Qt header file and include `#pragma warning(push, 0)` and `#pragma warning(pop)` at the right positions. I tried this once but gave up when the next Qt version was published.

Another possibility to reduce warnings is to disable specific warnings in the correct qmake.conf file (e.g. in mkspecs\win32-msvc2010).

I have changed some lines in this file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON    = -W4 -w34100 -w34189 -wd4127 -wd4512
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -Ox -MD
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -Ox -MD -Zi
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON  = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON
```

Answer (score 1):

We wrap our #include  blocks in pragmas to disable warnings.
Other than that we can only hope MS will implement isystem one day.
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/14717934-add-a-cl-exe-option-for-system-headers-like-gcc-s